# How to display a new element onClick of a bar recharts

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I have implemented bar chart using recharts. I would like to display a new div element outside the chart area when i click on the bar that would display additional information related to bar. I have added a function that will return a div element that needs to be displayed on onClick event.

[image]

```
<BarChart width={1130} height={450} data={data}>
                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                    <XAxis dataKey="endTime" tickFormatter={time => moment.unix(time).format('DD MMM')} />
                    <YAxis />
                    <Tooltip content={this.renderTooltip} />
                    <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36} />
                    <Brush dataKey='endTime' height={30} stroke="#1984CD" tickFormatter={time => moment.unix(time).format('DD MMM')} onChange={this.handleBrushChange.bind(this)} />
                    <Bar barSize={20} name="process duration" dataKey="duration" fill="#1984CD" onClick={this.onBarClick.bind(this)} />
                </BarChart>

onBarClick(bar) {
        console.log("bar clicked", bar);
        return (
            <div className='infoPanel'>
                <Box colorIndex="light-1" pad="small" margin="small">
                    <p>StartTime: {moment.unix(bar.startTime).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss')}</p>
                    <p>EndTime: {moment.unix(bar.endTime).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss')}</p>
                    <p>Event:  <span> {bar.aname}</span> {bar.evtime1}</p>
                    <p>Event: <span> {bar.aname2}</span>  {bar.evttime2}</p>
                    <p>Event: {bar.aname3} at {bar.evtime3}</p>
                </Box>
            </div>
        );
    }

.infoPanel {
  margin-top: 5em;
  color: #666;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

The function is getting called and run correctly but i don't see div element anywhere. Is it not possible to add new div element without adding a new component ?

Answer (score 1):

I have my method hope this helps :)

```
  const departmentCounts = accounts.reduce((counts, account) => {
const { department } = account;
const existingDepartment = counts.find(
  (item) => item.department === department
);

if (existingDepartment) {
  existingDepartment.Users++;
} else {
  counts.push({ department, Users: 1 });
}

return counts;
 }, []);

 return ( 
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
          <BarChart
            width={500}
            height={300}
            data={departmentCounts.sort((a, b) => b.Users - a.Users)}
            margin={{
              top: 5,
              right: 30,
              left: 20,
              bottom: 5,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="department" />
            <YAxis hide />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
            <Bar
              dataKey="Users"
              fill="#82ca9d"
              onClick={(e) => {
                const { payload } = e;
                console.log(payload);
              }}
            />
          </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>)
```

I have console.log the payload it returns like this

```
{department: 'Department 1', Users: 8}
```

you can make a function that would store the value of payload.value
ofcourse make a useState to store value of selectedBar;

```
 const [selectedBar, setSelectedBar] = useState({})
    const handleBarClicked = (payloadValue) => {
    setSelectedBar(payloadValue)
    }
    return(
    <>
     <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
          <BarChart
            width={500}
            height={300}
            data={departmentCounts.sort((a, b) => b.Users - a.Users)}
            margin={{
              top: 5,
              right: 30,
              left: 20,
              bottom: 5,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="department" />
            <YAxis hide />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
            <Bar
              dataKey="Users"
              fill="#82ca9d"
              onClick={(e) => {
                const { payload } = e;
                console.log(payload);
              }}
            />
          </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    {selectedBar && <div>{selectedBar}</div>}
     </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you are return the component but not rendering it anywhere. What you could do is a conditionnal rendering somewhere in your DOM and use a state to show or not what you are rendering.

For example you could have these two methods:

```
onBarClick(bar) {
  this.setState({selectedBar : bar});
}

 renderSelectedBar(bar) {
    return (
        <div className='infoPanel'>
            <Box colorIndex="light-1" pad="small" margin="small">
                <p>StartTime: {moment.unix(bar.startTime).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss')}</p>
                <p>EndTime: {moment.unix(bar.endTime).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss')}</p>
                <p>Event:  <span> {bar.aname}</span> {bar.evtime1}</p>
                <p>Event: <span> {bar.aname2}</span>  {bar.evttime2}</p>
                <p>Event: {bar.aname3} at {bar.evtime3}</p>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And then somewhere in your render function:

```
{ this.state.selectedBar ? this.renderSelectedBar(this.state.selectedBar) : undefined }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer googling around. Credits for the author not mine.

```
   const { 
    ResponsiveContainer, RadialBarChart, RadialBar, Legend, Tooltip
 } = Recharts;

const data = [
    {fill:"#008744", name:"A", uv:"5870"},
  {fill:"#d0ed57", name:"B", uv:"1"},
];

function demoOnClick(e) {
    alert(e.name);
}

const SimpleBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <RadialBarChart width={500} height={300} cx={150} cy={150} innerRadius={20} outerRadius={140} barSize={10} data={data} onClick={demoOnClick} >
          <Legend align="left" verticalAlign="top" />
          <RadialBar className="clickable" minAngle={15} label background clockWise={true} dataKey="uv" />
          <Tooltip />
        </RadialBarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ydycdLpx/5/

Answer (score 0):

**An end of 2023 Hooks Example**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { BarChart, Bar, CartesianGrid, XAxis, YAxis, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';
import { myApiFuncGetRechartData } from "../../../MyApiFile";

const ReChartBarChart = props => {  
    const [rechartBarData, setRechartBarData] = useState([])
    const [rechartBarJsx, setRechartBarJsx] = useState()

    //Here onClick find the summary text based on myname
    function demoOnClick(e) {
        let myname = e.value
        rechartBarData.forEach(
            res => {
                if(res.myname == myname){ //this assumes in my json response I have several objs that look like: {"myname":"pat", "score":3.2, "summary":"pat is a good student"}
                    alert(res.summary)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    //load in data with useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        myApiFuncGetRechartData().then(
            (response) => {
                setRechartBarData(response.data); 
            }
        )
    }, []);

    //plot Rechart and reload it every time data changes (rechartBarData)
    useEffect(() => {
        setRechartBarJsx(
            <ResponsiveContainer>
            <BarChart data={rechartBarData}  barSize={70} margin={{ top: 5, right: 0, left: -30, bottom: 0 }} layout="vertical" barCategoryGap={1}>
                <Bar dataKey="score" fill="rgba(148, 157, 234, 0.4)" />
                <CartesianGrid stroke="rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)" />
                <XAxis dataKey="score" type="number" style={{ display: 'none' }}> </XAxis>
                <YAxis onClick={demoOnClick}   dataKey="myname" axisLine={false} tickLine={false}  type="category" dx={105} style={{ fill: "white" }} />
                
            </BarChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
        )
    }, [rechartBarData]);

    return(
        <>
            {rechartBarJsx}
        </>
    )
};

export default ReChartBarChart;
```